# Bash script to read file, find certain lines and execute command

Tags: bash

I have a text file like this:

```
IP1 : date-time : bitcoin_address1
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address2
IP3 : date-time : bitcoin_address3
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make a script that reads this file (every hour, let's say, using crontab) and when finds something odd, to run a command.

What i specifically need it for the script to find lines with the same IP, but different bitcoin_address, like this:

```
IP1 : date-time : bitcoin_address1
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address2
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address3
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address4
IP3 : date-time : bitcoin_address5
```

and run a command on IP2. However, it's very important to run a command on IP2, only if bitcoin_address is different on each line, I don't want it to run a command for IP2, if the file is like this:

```
IP1 : date-time : bitcoin_address1
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address2
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address2
IP2 : date-time : bitcoin_address2
IP3 : date-time : bitcoin_address3
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly you could try the following..

```
    awk -F " : " '{ printf "%s_%s\n" , $1, $3 }' input.txt | sort | sed 's/\(\s*\)\(.*\)\(\s\)/\2/' | uniq | perl -pe 's/(\s*)(.*?)_(.*)/\2/' | uniq -d
```

I used an underscore as the delimiter. You might need to choose another one depending on the content of the actual live file.

The way this works is that it normalizes the rows, flattens the set to remove (full) row duplicates, extracts the IP prefixes and then flattens this set to identify duplicate IPs which have differing addresses. There are some additional clauses to trim spaces which you might wish to play with based on what guarantees you have about the content of the input file.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok great. Hopefully you will accept it as the answer. I am new here and need the points. Thanks

Comment: FYI, it's less efficient to run `cat input_file | foo` than to run `foo < input_file` -- or, in the case of `awk`, to pass the filename as an argument. `cat input_file | ...` gives you a FIFO connected to the `cat` command, meaning that `cat` needs to read the bytes and then write them to the pipeline before they're available to `awk`; the latter means `awk` has a handle on the file directly.

Comment: ...that's an even bigger deal when your command is `sort` instead of `awk`, as `sort` can split into multiple subprocesses, each of which sorts a section of the file, and then merge their results together... *if* it's able to seek around in the file, which is possible with a regular file handle, but not with a FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the duplicate ips with the following :

```
cut -d : -f 1,3 filename | sort | uniq -d | cut -d : -f 1 

cut -d -f 1,3
```

-d use : as a field delimiter
  -f output the first and third fields (IP and bitcoin)

```
sort
```

puts the file in order

```
uniq -d
```

outputs repeated lines in the file

```
cut -d -f 1
```

output the first field (IP)

you can pipe the output to `xargs` to execute the command of your choice, for example

```
cut -d : -f 1,3 filename | sort | uniq -d | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs echo hello $1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
However, for a file that looks like this:

    IP-1 : time-date : bitcoin-address-1
    IP-1 : time-date : bitcoin-address-2
    IP-1 : time-date : bitcoin-address-3
    IP-2 : time-date : bitcoin-address-4
    IP-2 : time-date : bitcoin-address-4
    IP-2 : time-date : bitcoin-address-4

won't the output be IP-1 and IP-2 aswell ? Or, in my case, i need the output to ONLY be IP-1. IP-2 has to be ignored.

Comment: edited the answer to first grab ip and bitcoin to look for duplicates